# C# Passing a collection as a collection of interfaces

Tags: c#, collections, interface, decoupling

I have simplified and reproduced my problem in the code below. The error that I am receiving is: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection

Some background for the design decisions that led to this issue: I have created a web service for dealing with "IFruit", but due to the nature of SOAP and endpoint bindings as I understand them I have created methods with explicit implementations of IFruit. On the business layer, creating a separate method for each specific implementation of fruit would firstly cause a lot of duplicate code, and secondly couple the business and service layer tightly enough that accepting new IFruit types in the web service later would also require changing my code in the business layer (adding another copy of redundant code). This design is one I have successfully implemented using Java in the past, but C# interfaces seem to be just different enough to throw me. Please advise.

```
public interface IFruit{
    public string TakeBite();
}

public Apple : IFruit{
    public string TakeBite(){
        return "tasty bite of apple";
    }
}

public void EatFruit(Collection<IFruit> fruits){
    foreach(var fruit in fruits){
        Console.WriteLine(fruit.TakeBite());
    }
}

public void EatApples(Collection<Apple> apples){
    this.EatFruit(apples);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try changing your `EatFruit` method to accept `IEnumerable<IFruit>`

```
public void EatFruit(IEnumerable<IFruit> fruits)
{
    foreach (var fruit in fruits)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fruit.TakeBite());
    }
}
```

The interface `IEnumerable<out T>` supports covariance since it is marked with the `out` modifier.  `Collection<T>` is not marked with such a modifier.

Answer (score 2):

That's called covariance.
However, it's not possible with mutable collections.

Otherwise, `EatFruit` could write

```
fruits.Add(new Orange());
```

.Net 4 does support covariance for reas-only interfaces, so you can change it to `IEnumerable<IFruit>` and it will work.

Comment: Assuming Orange implements IFruit then is there an issue there?

Comment: @Charleh: `fruits` is _actually_ a `Collection<Apple>`.  It can't hold an `Orange`.

Comment: I thought since fruits was a Collection<IFruit> that it could contain any type that implements IFruit?

Comment: @Charleh: He passed a `Collection<Apple>`, not a `Collection<IFruit>`.

Comment: Oh sorry completely missed the last method calling the previous :D

Comment: The idea is to reference a Collention<Apple> as a Collection<IFruit>. But it will always know it is a Collection<Apple> in its heart (fruits.GetType() will return Collection<Apple>).

Comment: @YouGotCSharpInMyJava: Yes.  And that's not safe.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using IEnumerable you could type check the collection (bit horrid but it should work):

```
public void EatApples(Collection<IFruit> fruit)
    var col = new Collection<IFruit>();

    fruit.Where(x => x is Apple).ToList().ForEach(x => col.Add(x));

    this.EatFruit(col);
}
```

Though I'd use IEnumerable instead - this is just an option if you can't refactor :P

(it's as type safe as you make it!)

Comment: That would do 2x work - create a List<Apple> then add each to the Collection. Better to do: `foreach (var x in fruit.OfType<Apple>()) { col.Add(x); }`.

Comment: Yeah true - nowhere did I say it would be performant (and I did mention horrid in there too!) :D

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution :

```
public void EatApples(Collection<Apple> apples){
     this.EatFruit(
          new Collection<IFruit>(
              apples.Cast<IFruit>()
          )
     );
}
```

Better solution : use the covariance introduced in C# 4 : see *Kevin*'s answer